# Replacing Nested Switch Statements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a multipurpose script for buttons that modify variables inside of my static game controller. When clicked, each should modify the correct variable that they are bound to by serialized enums. The idea being that I can slap them on any button and just change what they do to what data by changing a few flags on the button script instance.

The trouble comes with the number of possible permutations, I have two 'Armies' each with four 'Units' that have five 'Attributes' each. I end up with a really dense looking mess of code that I'm sure could be solved somehow but I can't find any solution.

(For clarity `activeArmy`, `unitToChange`, `unitNum`, and `attributeToChange` are all `enums`)

```
if (activeArmy == ArmyNum.army1)
{
    switch (attributeToChange)
    {
        case AttributeType.Accuracy:
            switch (unitToChange)
            {
                case UnitNum.unit1:
                    //if it's not too large
                    GameController.controller.army1.unit1.accuracy++;
                    //recalculate unit cost
                    GameController.controller.army1.unit1.RecalculateCost()
                    //then give the new number to the UI to display it
                    break;
```

Now I'd love to be able to do something like this:

```
GameController.controller.[activeArmy].[unitToChange].[attributeToChange]++;
```

Is that kind of pathing even possible? Is there a way to substitute in enums for paths to variables like that?

Is this something I'd solve by changing my architecture?

Comment: Maybe try to refactor the second switch into its own method. If that doesn't work, then I don't know

Comment: Just a quick caution, I see you are using `AttributeType`. Be warned that `System.Attribute` is probably in scope in most of your code, and that you don't want to get into a situation where you are possibly confusing C# attributes with your game attributes.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know. I had no idea that was a key word. I'll probably end up renaming the variable then.

Comment: It's not a keyword per se, but it is a member of `System` and you almost certainly have `using System;` in a lot of your files, so you will get it in scope for free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got the logic inside-out; that's what's creating your problem.  Do it in the other order, and break everything up into tiny methods:

```
Army GetArmy(ArmyNum a)
{
  switch(a)
  {
    case ArmyNum.army1: return controller.army1;
    ...
  }
}

Unit GetUnit(Army a, UnitNum u)
{
  switch(u)
  {
    case UnitNum.unit1: return a.unit1;
    ...
  }
}

void ChangeAttribute(GameAttribute a, Army a, Unit u)
{
  switch (attributeToChange) {
    case GameAttribute.Accuracy:
      u.accuracy += 1;
      break;
      ...
```

And now the call site is simply:

```
Army a = GetArmy(activeArmy);
Unit u = GetUnit(a, unitToChange);
ChangeAttribute(attributeToChange, a, u);
```

The lesson here is **make small methods each of which does one thing extremely well**.  Then compose more complex methods out of those smaller methods.

Once you have done so, then you can start to change your implementation details.  For example, we might notice that `GetUnit` is properly a method of `Army`, so we'd change its signature to

```
Unit GetUnit(UnitNum u) // Now a method of Army
{
  switch(u)
  {
    case UnitNum.unit1: return this.unit1; // this, not 'a'.
    ...
  }
}
```

And now the call site is

```
Army a = GetArmy(activeArmy);
Unit u = a.GetUnit(unitToChange);
ChangeAttribute(attributeToChange, a, u);
```

which is plainly better.

Now suppose you make a `Dictionary<ArmyNum, Army>` called `Armies`.  You then rewrite:

```
Army GetArmy(ArmyNum a) => Armies[a];
```

And similarly for GetUnits.  Once you're there, you can find sites where you use `GetArmy` and `GetUnit` and replace it with `Armies[a]` and `Armies[a].Units[u]` and so on.

Your notion of moving towards a world where everything is parameterized is a good idea. **Get there gradually** by making **small changes, each one of which is plainly correct**.

An **advanced** solution would be to make the actions associated with *delegates*:

```
actions = new Dictionary<GameAttribute, Action<Army, Unit>>() 
{
  { Attribute.Accuracy, (a, u) => { u.accuracy += 1; } }, 
  ...
};
```

and then you could write:

```
a = Armies[army];
u = a.Units[unit]
actions[attribute](a, u);
```

But walk before you run! As your program logic gets more complex, you will find that you are again making huge messes of complicated code, and then you'll try to organize it into classes using good OO principles, and **that could make it worse**.  I wrote a series of articles on how using OO to attempt to solve these sorts of problems goes wrong; if this topic interests you, see https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Comment: This was the answer I was in the process of writing :)
I also wonder if enums and switches are really the best solution, especially for the Army and Unit level. Would not a simple collection and an index be easier?

Comment: Thank you! This really helps. I learned a lot just by reading it.

Comment: @JamesTaggart: You're welcome. Your current logic is quite amenable to being broken down into small parts like this, but as your game logic gets more complex, you're going to run into the problem of "what happens when cavalry armed with lances meets footmen defending with pikes on a hillside in the rain?" and so on. It is very easy to write an even more huge mess than the one you've already got!  I wrote a series about how attempts to solve this problem with traditional OO programming fail, though I don't really offer a concrete solution. You might find it interesting. I'll add a link.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a flexible architecture that you could try.  I'd recommend using string identifiers for your armies/units/attributes instead of enums because with enums you're locking your into a set list of values, and you could never have more armies or units that what's in your enum.

If you keep using enums, set the `Army`/`Unit`/`Attribute` objects' `Name` property to the enum's `ToString` value to make this code work.  For example, `army.Name = ArmyTypes.Navy.ToString()`

```
public class Army
{
    // The army's name
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // List of units in the army
    public List<Unit> Units { get; set; }

    // Get the named unit from this army
    public Unit GetUnit(string name)
    {
        foreach (var unit in this.Units)
        {
            // Case insensitive comparison
            if (string.Compare(unit.Name, name, true) == 0)
            {
                return unit;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class Unit
{
    // The unit's name
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // The unit's attributes
    public List<UnitAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }

    // Get the named attribute from this army
    public UnitAttribute GetAttribute(string name)
    {
        foreach (var attribute in this.Attributes)
        {
            if (string.Compare(attribute.Name, name, true) == 0)
            {
                return attribute;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class UnitAttribute
{
    // The attribute's name
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Current attribute value and maximum attribute value
    public int CurrentValue { get; set; }
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }

    // Add a value to this attribute and don't let it go above its maximum
    public void Add(int value)
    {
        this.CurrentValue += value;
        if (this.CurrentValue > this.MaxValue)
        {
            this.CurrentValue = this.MaxValue;
        }
    }
}

public class Controller
{
    public List<Army> Armies { get; set; }

    // I'd recommend using string parameters for your buttons instead 
    // of enum parameters, but you can do it either way
    public void ModifyUnitButtonHandler(ArmyTypes army, UnitTypes unit, UnitAttributeTypes attribute, int value)
    {
        // I'm not sure if the ? operator exists in Unity's default .NET version.
        // If not, you can use a few if/then statements to make sure that nothing
        // returns null
        GetArmy(army.ToString())?
            .GetUnit(unit.ToString())?
            .GetAttribute(attribute.ToString())?
            .Add(value);
    }

    private Army GetArmy(string name)
    {
        foreach (var army in this.Armies)
        {
            if (string.Compare(name, army.Name, true) == 0)
            {
                return army;
            }                
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a reasonable architecture. As I just noted in a comment to the original poster, try to avoid using `Attribute` as it is too easily confused with `System.Attribute`.